# How to create a dynamic 3d table in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a List of Ordersheet which contains the following properties.

```
OrderSheet {
  String orderId;
  List<ProductModel> product;
  String customerName;
}

ProductModel{
String name;
Int quantity;
 }
List<OrderSheet> orders;
```

I want to create a table of columns containing customer name, total and rows of products. But the products should not repeat. Say customer A got 1 apple and customer B got 2 apples.
The row should show only apple = 3 on total column

However each row will show the quantity of products that belongs to the customer.

[image: order sheet]

This is what I have so far for columns

```
List<DataColumn> getColumns() {
    return orders
        .map((order) => DataColumn(label: Text(order.customerName)))
        .toList();
  }
```

But I'm a little confused on how to display the rows. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Syncfussion DataGride](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/datagrid/overview) package.

Comment: I updated my question. Would you take a look

Comment: The easiest way would be for you is to learn SQFlite https://www.sqltutorial.org. There is a package on this for flutter. Then, in each cell you could call a query e.g. when you want to display how many bananas user no 1 bought, you call SELECT USER_ 1 FROM TABLE WHERE PRODUCT = 'Banana';. Play with excel if you want to learn logic in advance.

Comment: Appreciate the help